# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getParts()

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets

I added maven dependencies servlet-api 2.5, javaee-web-api 6.0, but I still get this exceptions.
Any help would be very much appreciated =) Thanks.

```
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getParts()Ljava/util/Collection;
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:57)
  at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:58)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:883)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
```

Comment: please check that the server you run the application on also supports this version of the API

Comment: please paste some code from StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java with all imports

Answer (score 3):

According to me, following may be the problem.
your code is referring some Other `HttpServletRequest` at compile time which has a method called `getParts()` and at runtime(when you are deploying your project and running) it is referring `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` for resolution and it is not finding any such method.

check in your code(imports) which package is it referring for `HttpServletRequest` class resolution

i can also see that [**servlet API 2.5**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/) **does not have any such method** in `HttpServletRequest` class while [**javaee-web-api 6.0**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/) **does** you can remove unwanted dependancy and also you need to make sure the dependancy you used is available to your code at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Jetty 6 (servlet spec 2.5), the `HttpServletRequest` object doesn't have the Servlet 3.0 `getParts()` method. You need to get an other servlet container (upgrade to Jetty 9) to get this working.